# Is there a way to implement month picker in React day picker?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-day-picker

I have two conditions,

- One is to select the whole week, select any date, it will automatically select all the days of the week

  - I think this condition has a good chance of being fulfilled
- One is to select a month. After successful selection, all dates of the current month will be automatically selected.
- [Select a diagram of the week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1lo7.gif)
- [Select the current month chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8yTS.gif)